# How to render reverse fields using related name between foreign key models

Tags: django

I have two models if a foreign key relationship and a related name. I return a queryset of `Foo` and want to render fields of the related object `Bar`. However, `item.link.value` doesn't render anything.

```
# Models

class Foo(models.Model):
    item


class Bar(models.Model:
    foo = models.Foreignkey(Foo, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='link')
    value = models.Charfield(max_length=20)
```

```
# View

def test(request):

    qs = Foo.objects.all()

    context = {
    'qs': qs
    }

return render (request, 'somepage.html', context)
```

```
# Template

{% for item in qs %}
<div> {{ item.link.value }} </div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try changing your queryset to return instances of `Bar`, which has the `value` attribute.

First update your related name on the `Bar` model to the plural, `links`:

```
# Models

class Foo(models.Model):
    item


class Bar(models.Model:
    foo = models.Foreignkey(Foo, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='links')
    value = models.Charfield(max_length=20)
```

If you now ask for `Foo.links.all()`, Django will return a queryset of `Bar` instances.

```
# View
def test(request):

    qs = Foo.links.all()

    context = {
    'qs': qs
    }

return render (request, 'somepage.html', context)
```

Comment: and how what the template rendering look like?

Comment: It should be fine the way you have it

Comment: how to adapt this to a filtered queryset? Right now in my live project I have `comments_qs = Comment.objects.filter(poller_id=poller_id)` as queryset "Foo". Like I have a filtered Foo queryset and want to attach the Bar fields to these filtered Foo objects

Comment: The syntax for filtering is correct, however, you are getting back instances of  the `Comment` object. If you want `Foo` objects, you will need to do `Foo.objects.filter(key=value)`

Comment: ah it's hard for me to express. I want to "attach" the fields of Foo to the instances of the comment object in queryset `comments_qs`. Because the qs in your answer doesn't contain any data about the Foo objects, does it? Since I don't want to fetch all comment objects, only a filtered set that has access to the fields of Bar.

Comment: I'm sorry I am trying to understand as best I can. No, you are quering the `Bar` objects if you want to display the `value` attribute like in your template. `value` does not exist on the `Foo` object. Could you add the `comment` object to your question?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/237426/discussion-between-andries-d-niemandt-and-jonas).